# не удается использовать pillow

Tags: python, импорт, pillow

моя программа содержит строку

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

и при запуске получаю ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\vys\Лаба 2\pythonProject\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

я установил через терминал пайчарма:

```sh
pip install Pillow
```

установка прошла успешно: `Successfully installed pip-23.1`, но по-прежнему ловлю ту же ошибку....

Comment: Поставили в одно место, Питон запускаете из другого.

Comment: Вы используете PyCharm?

Comment: А почему Successfully installed **pip**-23.1?